# how to select column3 from rec1 value which is matched to column1 val in rec2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

i am having following scenario :

```
  col1 col2 col3 
   10   2    13
   13   4    14
   14   5    15
   15   6    16
```

form the above given table col3 value(13) in row1 is seen in col1 value(13) in row2 and this chain continues...

here my input column is col1 and i have to get col3 value where the chain ends up
condition is col3 value should match with next row col1 value.

example input-----> col1 = 10,
           output----->col3 = 16.

another table :

```
col1 col2 col3 
151   6    162
162   4    163
163   67   164
102   2    101
101   4    107
107   5    103
v1    2    v2
v2    4    v3
v3    5    v5
```

here is my input -->(151,v1,102) , output---->(164,v5,103)

unfortunately, i am not supposed to use stored procedures.

i am struggling on this for couple of hours...please help me.

Comment: can you give another table, with the expected output.

Comment: @g2server i have updated my question with another table

Comment: Who is telling you you are "not supposed to use stored procedures"? Also, a query is a query, whether it is contained inside a stored procedure or not. I don't know why people state these artificial and meaningless constraints...

Answer (score -1):

you can use the LAG or LEAD functions
([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125.aspx))

or you can use recurrsion with CTE,

CTE example:

```
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TBL') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TBL
    CREATE TABLE #TBL
    (
        COL1 INT NOT NULL,
        COL2 INT NOT NULL,
        COL3 INT NOT NULL
    )
    INSERT #TBL
            ( COL1, COL2, COL3 )
    VALUES  ( 10,2,13),(13,4,14),(14,5,15),(15,6,16)

    DECLARE @INPUT INT = 10
    --This is the only part you need
    ;WITH ReccursiveCTE AS (
    SELECT TOP 1 COL1,COL2,COL3,1 LVL FROM #TBL WHERE COL1 = @INPUT
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  T.COL1 ,
            T.COL2 ,
            T.COL3,
            C.LVL + 1 FROM ReccursiveCTE C
    INNER JOIN #TBL T ON C.COL3 = T.COL1
    )
    SELECT TOP 1 COL3 AS Result FROM ReccursiveCTE ORDER BY LVL desc
--end
```

:)

shimon.

Comment: i cannot use stored procedures

Comment: thats not a stored procedure... and you dont need the create table / drop table / insert parts of the code because you allready have the data and table

Comment: oh can i use it directly as query ..let me try this

Comment: i have tried it in ---http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f4f24/2 ..its throws an error

Comment: hey if i give input value from middle of records its giving me wrong value can u plz check here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/afea6/5

Comment: LAG and LEAD are SQL Server 2012 onwards and will not work in 2008

Comment: iam using 2012 plz see this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/aeffb/2

Comment: you cant use it with in(value1,value2,...)

Comment: run the cte/query for each one of the inputs you have and you will get correct results

Comment: but if i have too many inputs?...and actually its third part DB..connecting too many time will effects the performance..

Comment: so you need to use a stored procedure or collect the table data once on each run to a local db and run the query there

Comment: and you should check to see if its really damages the performance because you cant guess stuff like that without making a real check